# Testing a Promise with an interval

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am writing a service in AngularJS. I need to be able to test this service. I have everything working, except for one piece. Currently, the function that I want to test is defined like this:

```
return {
  triggerError: false,
  watchers: [],

  createWatcher : function (options) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var watchId = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1);

    var delay = 10000;
    if (options && options.milliseconds) {
      delay = options.milliseconds;
    }

    this.watchers.push($interval(
      function() {
        if (this.triggerError) {
          defer.reject('There was an error watching.');
        }

        // Generate a random number
        var randomA = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1);
        var randomB = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1);
        var result = { a: randomA, b: randomB };
        defer.notify(result);   
      },
      delay
    ));

    return {
      watchId: watchId,
      promise: defer.promise 
    };
  }
}
```

As the name implies, this function creates a watcher that will fire on an interval. The reason that it is written like this is because I need to be consistent with another framework that's in use.  For that reason, I need to be able to make the following call in my code:

```
var watcher = myService.createWatcher({...});
watcher.promise.then(
  function() { ... },
  function(err) {},
  function(result) {
    console.log('A: ' + result.a);
    console.log('B: ' + result.b);
  }
)
```

I need to be able to write a test that will wait for the watcher to fire 10 times. Currently, I have the following:

```
it('should fire ten times', function(done) {
  var count = 0;
  var watch = myService.creationWatcher({});

  watch.promise.then(
    function() { console.log('here 1'); },
    function(err) { console.log('here 2'); },
    function(result) {
        count = count + 1;
    console.log(result);
    }
  );

  interval.flush(5000);
  rootScope.$digest();
});
```

I see it print 'here 1'. However, I'm not sure if I've written my test incorrectly, or if I'm missing something in my service. In my opinion, my service looks correct. However, I'm unsure about the test itself. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I can't figure out why my test won't wait for the watcher to fire 10 times.

Thank you!

Comment: your `delay = 10000;` while `interval.flush(5000);` , is it a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your delay in the test is set too low. When you use

```
interval.flush(100000)
```

instead it should work - although it looks like your code will not run as-is, I had to make some adjustments.

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simongroenewolt/yfbthb6t/3/) to show you it works with a higher delay (with some small fixes). If you have questions like this in the future, including code in the question but also a fiddle will greatly help others helping you :-)

BTW: I'm assuming the `creationWatcher()` in your testing code was a typo and the actual function to be called should be `createWatcher()`.

Comment: This fiddle shows what I'd expect in the console. The question confused me because the asker stated that he saw `"here 1"`, even though that is in the `success` function for `.then()`, and the promise is never resolved. Strange.